# Get feed from facebook of an logged user

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, facebook

I have been trying to get facebook page feed  with jquery. I have included the code following which i have been tried

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $menuLeft = $('.pushmenu-left');
        $nav_list = $('#nav_list');
        $nav_list2 = $('#nav_list2');

        $nav_list.click(function () {
            $(this).toggleClass('active');
            $('.pushmenu-push').toggleClass('pushmenu-push-toright');
            $menuLeft.toggleClass('pushmenu-open');
        });

        $nav_list2.click(function () {
            alert("clicked");
            window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
                FB.init({
                    appId: '1647252837xxxxx',
                    status: true,
                    cookie: true,
                    xfbml: true
                });
                FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function (response) {
                    alert("clicked 2");
                    if (response.status === 'connected') {
                        alert("connected");
                        testAPI();
                    } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
                        alert("connected");
                        FB.login();
                    } else {
                        alert("connected");
                        FB.login();
                    }
                });
            };
            (function (d) {
                var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
                if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
                js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
                js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
                ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
            }(document));

            function testAPI() {
                console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
                FB.api('/me', function (response) {
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
                    var name = response.name;
                    $.get('https://graph.facebook.com/111222778066/feed?access_token=ba965d29c16c605d252f5f500cf58baa',
                              function (data) {
                              }, "jsonp");
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

I cannot find any error in console. And I don't know  any further steps to follow.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What's the current output?